# Remove name attribute - Form API

Tags: 7, forms

For PCI compliance reasons, I need to remove the `name` attribute from a form field.

I have tried:

(1)

```
$form['field']= array(
    '#name'=>'',
)
```

(2)

```
$form['field']= array(
    '#name'=>false,
)
```

3)

```
$form['field']= array(
    '#attributes' => array('name' => ''),
)
```

(4)

```
$form['field']= array(
    '#attributes' => array('name' => false),
)
```

None of the above work (each of the above produce a field with the `name` attribute present, just empty. I need it removed altogether).

I haven't managed to achive it with the `hook_form_alter` hook either.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's a textfield, I think the simplest way would be via a preprocess on [`theme_textfield`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_textfield/7.x):

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_textfield(&$vars) {
  // Identify the element and remove the name property (which will always be present)
  if ($vars['element']['#foo'] == 'bar') {
    unset($vars['element']['#name'];
  }
}
```

Bear in mind that Drupal won't be able to process the value for that field correctly if you submit the form, but I guess you're submitting this offsite anyway.

If it's not a textfield you should be able to use the same principle with the the theme function for whatever element type you're using.